# Finding where a running sum of a time series is above given threshold

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have some time series data. For example look at the following values (Lets assume time here is minutes):

```
User Time Value
a   0      10
b   1      100
c   2      200
a   3      5
e   4      7
a   5      999
a   6      8
b   7      10
a   8      10
a   9      10
a   10     10
a   11     10
a   12     100
```

Now I want to find out if within any given 5 minute intervals a total SUM of more than 1000 is achieved.

For example in the above example I should get an output such as user a, minute 5,6,8,9.

Comment: why can't the result be 0,3,5 for user `a`?because the sum exceeds 1000 in this case too.

Comment: Isn't 5-10 a 6-minute interval?

Comment: Define what you mean by a 5-minute interval. Is it set time periods, eg. 0-4, 5-9, etc, or is it the 5 minutes before/after the current row?

Comment: Lad : Oracle.. Boneist : a rolling 5 minute window. So it is not set time periods. vkp : No as time 0 - 5 it doesnt exceed 1000. Hambone : You are right - question edited.

Comment: Modified my solution to match your 5 minute window...

Comment: What with `a 22 999` and `a 23 2` ? Should it return both or only second? Should your window work only backward as in accepted answer?

Comment: @CodeGeek123 - I updated my version of the answer to resolve a problem noticed by lad2025, so you might want to double-check your implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an easy task for Window Function:

```
select *
from 
 (
   select t.*
     ,sum("Value") -- cumulative sum over the previous five minutes
      over (partition by "user"
            order by "Time"
            range 4 preceding) as sum_5_minutes
   from Table1 t
 ) dt
where sum_5_minutes > 1000
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fcc94/6)

Edit: SQLFiddle is offline again, but you can also search the next 5 minutes.

Edit2: SQLFiddle offline, but if the datatype is a `TimeStamp` or `Date` you must use intervals instead of integers:

```
select *
from 
 (
  select t.*
     ,sum("Value") 
      over (partition by "User"
            order by "Time"
            range interval '4' minute preceding) as sum_prev5_minutes
      ,sum("Value") 
      over (partition by "User"
            order by "Time"
            range between interval '0' minute preceding -- or "current row" if there are no duplicate timestamps
            and interval '4' minute following) as sum_next5_minutes

   from Table1 t
 ) dt
where sum_prev5_minutes > 1000 
   or sum_next5_minutes > 1000
```

Comment: `PARTITION BY "user"`?

Comment: Thanks for that Dnoeth.. However my question was to apply this to a more granular level where the data isnt necessarily stored as above. I have micro second time stamps but need a window on seconds - how would you do this? I wondererd if there was a more generic solution?

Comment: **This does not work correctly** `INTO Table1 ("User", "Time", "Value")
         VALUES ('a', 22, 999)
                      INTO Table1 ("User", "Time", "Value")
         VALUES ('a', 23, 2)` Will show only second row, because window function get rows backward (fiddle is down so no demo this time)

Comment: @CodeGeek - The RANGE  vaue PROCEEDING allows you to use pretty much any functional calculation (including column values) to set your range for the window, so if your data is in microseconds you would set your window to 5000 ms. If you want it generic, parameterize it to set the window value at runtime.

Comment: **[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c30e5a/1/0)**. This is problem with windowed function becauseyou search only backward.

Comment: @lad2025 - you are correct. It needs to push this into a subquery to join back to the table and cover the range of timestamps that are caught in the window. I have updated my answer below....

Comment: @CodeGeek123: In the beginning I thought you only want to consider the previous minutes, but the window can also be in the *following* direction, so simply check 5 minutes in both directions.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton Thanks for the clarification. I tried using a number to set my range, e.g : order by Time range 5000 preceding, but i get the error invalid data type.

Comment: @CodeGeek123: What's the actual datatype of `time`? Try something like `between current row and interval '4' minutes following

Comment: @dnoeth it is timestamp. This works : numtodsinterval('1', 'second')

Comment: @CodeGeek123: Have a lokal my edit, changed to `Interval` calculations.

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate my comment to dnoeth's post, and so don't take my answer as correct as he did the heavy lifting and deserves the green checkmark, the following shows how you can set the range at runtime...

```
WITH DAT AS (
SELECT 'a' u,   0 t,     10 v from dual union all
SELECT 'b' u,   1 t,       100 v from dual union all
SELECT 'c' u,   2 t,       200 v from dual union all
SELECT 'a' u,   3 t,       5 v from dual union all
SELECT 'e' u,   4 t,       7 v from dual union all
SELECT 'a' u,   5 t,       999 v from dual union all
SELECT 'a' u,   6 t,       8 v from dual union all
SELECT 'b' u,   7 t,       10 v from dual union all
SELECT 'a' u,   8  t,      10 v from dual union all
SELECT 'a' u,   9 t,       10 v from dual union all
SELECT 'a' u,   10 t,      10 v from dual union all
SELECT 'a' u,   11 t,      10 v from dual union all
SELECT 'a' u,   12 t,      100 v from dual )
  -- imaging passing a variable in to this second query, setting it in a config table, or whatever. 
  -- This is just showing that you don't have to hard-code it into the actual select clause, and that the value can be determined at runtime.
, wind as (select 5 rng from dual)
select d.*
     ,sum(v) -- cumulative sum over the previous five minutes
      over (partition by u order by t
            range w.rng preceding) as sum_5_minutes
   from dat d
      join wind w on 1=1
   order by u,t;
```

I also note that lad2025 is correct that this windowing WILL miss some rows in the set. To correct that you need to bring back all rows in the set over the range for a user where the preceeding five seconds exceed 1000. This works correctly for user Z below, but would have only brought back the second row as originally coded.

```
WITH DAT AS (
SELECT 'a' u,   0 t,     10 v from dual union all
SELECT 'b' u,   1 t,       100 v from dual union all
SELECT 'c' u,   2 t,       200 v from dual union all
SELECT 'a' u,   3 t,       5 v from dual union all
SELECT 'e' u,   4 t,       7 v from dual union all
SELECT 'a' u,   5 t,       999 v from dual union all
SELECT 'a' u,   6 t,       8 v from dual union all
SELECT 'b' u,   7 t,       10 v from dual union all
SELECT 'a' u,   8  t,      10 v from dual union all
SELECT 'a' u,   9 t,       10 v from dual union all
SELECT 'a' u,   10 t,      10 v from dual union all
SELECT 'a' u,   11 t,      10 v from dual union all
-- two Z rows added. In the initial version only the second row would be caught.
SELECT 'z' u,   10 t,      999 v from dual union all
SELECT 'z' u,   11 t,      10 v from dual union all
SELECT 'a' u,   12 t,      100 v from dual )
, wind as (select 3 rng from dual)
SELECT dd.*, sum_5_minutes
from dat dd
JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM ( 
        select d.*
             ,sum(v) -- cumulative sum over the previous five minutes
              over (partition by u order by t
                    range w.rng preceding) as sum_5_minutes
             ,min(t) -- start point of the range that we are covering
              over (partition by u order by t
                    range w.rng preceding) as rng_5_minutes
           from dat d
              join wind w on 1=1
   ) WHERE    sum_5_minutes > 1000 ) fails
on dd.u = fails.u
and dd.t >= fails.rng_5_minutes
and dd.t <= fails.t           
order by dd.u, dd.t;
```

Comment: Nice ****. At least one person understand my concerns. **[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c30e5a/8/0)**

Comment: To be fair, the OP's statement on which records would be caught in the query were correctly selected by dnoeth's query. The question then is what constitutes the records that really should be selected for the interval. Based on a true 5-minute moving window, I agree that your definition seems accurate and that the OP might want to reconsider..

Comment: @MichaelBroughton: The Window definition can be also in the *following* direction, see my edited answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at this:

```
select
  s1."user", s1."time", sum (s2."value") as five_minute_value
from
  sample s1
  left join sample s2 on
    s1."user" = s2."user" and
    s1."time" between s2."time" and s2."time" + 4
group by
  s1."user", s1."time"
having
  sum (s2."value") > 1000
```

Output on your data:

```
a   8   1017
a   9   1027
a   6   1012
a   5   1004
```

Comment: Counterexample **[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d10412/1/0)**, only second record, even if both are in 5 minutes range